# Call a function without storing the value returned

Tags: java, function

Is it all right to call a function that returns a value without storing the value returned in a variable?
Here is some sample code:

```
class Test
{ 
  int days[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

  boolean validity()
  { 
     //some code
     isLeap();
  }

  boolean isLeap(int y)
  {
       if(y%400==0 || (y%100!=0 && y%4==0))
       {
          days[1] = 29;             
          return true; 
       }
       else
       {
          days[1] = 28;         
          return false;
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: The compiler allows it.

Comment: you have to do `return isLeap();` so you can compile, but it's valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. The compiler won't throw an error. But in your case it does not make any sense to use up processor time for something unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is allowed

In your code example, it's not good coding style...  A function called isLeap(xxx) is updating data.  I don't think most people would be expecting the side-effect of the data being updated in a function like this.
Unintended side-effects can lead to some nasty bugs down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can call a function but never store the returned value by that function in java.
But it will just unnecessarily consume processing time.
Because you will not be achieving what you want to achieve by first declaring that you want some processing to be done by method and return a final output.
If you are not storing it won't be any useful.